# I want to load the yahoo in frame

Tags: load, frame, yahoo

I am trying to load yahoo.com in a frame in a html page with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<frameset rows="1%,99%" >
  <frame src="headframe.html">
  <frame src="http://www.yahoo.com">
</frameset>
</html>
```

but it doesn't show anything on the page.
I test another website and it works correctly .
why this problem is happening and what's the solution ?
thank you.

Comment: I want to add a js code to this site AFTER site loads at my computer . What do you suggest to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo sends the [`X-Frame-Options: DENY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header to prevent you from framing their website. There is no real workaround, as this is a security feature in modern browsers that allows website to refuse framing, mainly to protect against [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking). Your code will only work in older browsers that do not have this security feature, and even then there may be frame-busting JavaScript to break out of your frame or otherwise render the page useless.

Comment: this answer is true for youtube also and i think even for google  :)